# Identify snap apps in the apt repository (before having them installed)

Tags: apt, snap, offline

Since I am using my servers in an offline environment I usually mirror the ubuntu archive - works perfectly!
Now *shocking* I found that chromium-browser is a snap app in U20.04 LTS. So it does not install unless you are really connected to the internet. This renders the idea of apt-mirror completely useless.

I just wonder if there are any other apps using snap. And I like to know this before I continue migrating all servers.

Maybe I have to walk through each apt package and see if it has a snap dependency?

thx

Comment: There is no single list or master plan that we can point you to. Each project decides for themselves if they wish to distribute by deb or snap or something else, and they can change their minds at any time. The Chromium packagers, for example, switched because it reduced their workload.

Comment: the only idea from me first make a simulation. `apt -s install package-name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of apt packages can't have snap apps as dependency(unless it is a Transitional package) and most of snap apps can't have apt packages as dependency(only snapd).

**Extra helpful commands:**

Use `snap info <app>` to see info about snap apps and `apt info <package>` to see info about apt packages.

Use `snap list` to see all packages installed by snap and `apt list --installed` to see all packages installed by apt, it can be a very long list.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the reverse dependencies of the `snapd`-package:

```
$ apt rdepends snapd | grep "Depends"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reverse Depends:
  Depends: snap-confine (= 2.57.5+22.04ubuntu0.1)
  Depends: ubuntu-snappy-cli
  Depends: ubuntu-snappy
  Depends: ubuntu-core-snapd-units
  Depends: ubuntu-core-launcher (= 2.57.5+22.04ubuntu0.1)
  Depends: snapd-xdg-open (= 2.57.5+22.04ubuntu0.1)
  Depends: snap-confine (= 2.55.3+22.04)
  Depends: plasma-discover-backend-snap
  Depends: gnome-software-plugin-snap
  Depends: ubuntu-image
  Depends: livecd-rootfs (>= 2.39)
  Depends: ubuntu-snappy-cli
  Depends: ubuntu-snappy
  Depends: ubuntu-core-snapd-units
  Depends: ubuntu-core-launcher (= 2.55.3+22.04)
  Depends: snapd-xdg-open (= 2.55.3+22.04)
  PreDepends: snapcraft
  Depends: livecd-rootfs (>= 2.39)
  Depends: plasma-discover-backend-snap
  Depends: gnome-software-plugin-snap
  PreDepends: ember
  PreDepends: cyphesis-cpp
  PreDepends: chromium-browser
  Depends: ubuntu-server-minimal
  Depends: ubuntu-image
  PreDepends: firefox
```

We could even shorten the list if we look for `PreDepends`:

```
~$ apt rdepends snapd | grep "PreDepends"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

  PreDepends: snapcraft
  PreDepends: ember
  PreDepends: cyphesis-cpp
  PreDepends: chromium-browser
  PreDepends: firefox
```

This are the transitional packages which install the applications as a snap package. The output may differ depending on the Ubuntu version you use.

Comment: ... or more directly `apt --important --no-depends rdepends snapd` or `aptitude search '~Dpredepends:snapd'`